# Angular 2 service function is returning Undefined to component

Tags: angular

I'm returning array from to `Component` from `Service` while reading. But I'm getting undefined in component instead of array result in component.

Service:

```
 getItems(): Promise<any>{
        var items = [{id:1}{id:2}{id:3}];
        return Promise.resolve(items);
    }
```

Component A:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
          this.service.getItems()
              .then(result => this.items= result);
          console.log(this.items);
      }
  );
```

}

Comment: move your `console.log(this.items);` in .then and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `then` is working after the statement `console.log(this.items);`, because it is asynchronous. So before assigning you print your `items` and why it is undefined. Put your `console.log` into the function passed to `then`.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
     this.service.getItems()
           .then(result => { 
               this.items= result;
               console.log(this.items);
           });
}
```

**See example**

See the sequence of the `console.log`s.

```js
let items = [];

function getItems() {
   const arr = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}];
   return Promise.resolve(arr);
}
    
getItems().then(result => {
   items = result;
   console.log(`Second - ${items}`);
});

console.log(`First - ${items}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

in service.ts

```
getItems(): Promise<any> {
        var items = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];
        return Promise.resolve(items);
    }
```

in component.ts

```
private items: Array<any> = [];
ngOnInit(): void {
        this.service.getItems()
            .then(result => {
                this.items = result
                console.log('this.items', this.items);
            }
```

)
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
          this.service.getItems()
              .then(result => this.items= result);
          console.log(this.items);
      }
  );
```

> The service is a asynchronous call and it takes some time to resolve the promise where as by
>   console logging immediately, you log it in a synchronous context by
>   that time the this.items is undefined .

Move the console.log inside the then then it will work fine like

```
    .then(result => {
        this.items = result
        console.log(this.items);
    }
```